# SQL Return only specific characters in SELECT from VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on an issue in SQL Server. I have a `VARCHAR` column called `Name` in my table:

[image]

I am trying to get the column to only return valid characters when doing a select on it. For example, I am only accepting any letters [A-Z], numbers [0-9] or a question mark [?] but list can change so need to be flexible. The reason why I am only accepting certain characters is due to our supplier specification which I send data to. It will break their system if I send then an invalid character.

```
SELECT Name FROM @table
```

For the purpose of asking the question, I have included a small example below where I insert into a table variable. My question is aimed towards the select part as I am trying to work on data already inserted.

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
(
    ID INT ,
    Name VARCHAR(500) ,
    Age INT 
)

INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES (1, 'Hello ## World! Test8.?##', 23), 
       (2, 'Need specific characters only Test8.? ]]', 22)

-- Only accept [A-Z][0-9][?]
SELECT Name FROM @table
```

Please note, the scenario above is a small example and the data is just dummy data I just added to make it easier to ask the question. The data already exist. I have no control over it. I only have access to it and need to tidy it up via doing a select.

Expected results with only returning valid characters:

[image]

For first row it will return "Hello  World Test8?" and for second row it will return "Need specific chatacters only Test8?".

What I have tried so far is doing a replace on the select to get the result:

```
-- Only accept [A-Z][0-9][?]
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, '#', ''), '!', ''), ']', ''), '.', '') FROM @table
```

However, this only works if I knew which characters are invalid. As mentioned earlier in question, I only know the opposite which are valid characters. A valid character is a letter [A-Z] or number [0-9] or a question mark. This means I have a massive list of invalid characters I need to add if I went towards a replace solution.

Any idea how I can achieve this within the select statement?

I am on SQL Server Version 2012.

Comment: You're probably better off cleaning your data in the client code or reporting tool.

Comment: And why don't you want `Hello World Test8.?` ? The period is also okay? - not indicated in your narrative.

Comment: Look into using Insert Triggers (I'm assuming SQL Server), https://databasefaqs.com/sql-server-trigger-after-insert/

Comment: Could you provide your expected results. Do you want to exclude names that contain accepted characters or do you want to strip other characters from all names?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  I need the full varchar for other process. The reason why I am only accepting certain characters is due to our supplier specification which I sent data to. It will break their system.

Comment: @June7 I have updated the question. The reason why I am only accepting certain characters is due to our supplier specification which I sent data to. It will break their system. I want to be flexible with a solution in case I need to add more valid characters.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: @PeterSmith I have updated the question with excepted result. I want all rows to return from the table with only valid characters in them.

Comment: Text processing in SQL is generally awful. Clean your data at ingestion time, in another language, not at report time. (There's no reason you can't retain both the original and cleaned variations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this, though this was implemented by people before:

https://raresql.com/2013/03/11/sql-server-function-to-parse-alphanumeric-characters-from-string/

Using this (all copyrights to the author) would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[UDF_Extract_Alphanumeric_From_String]
(
@String VARCHAR(MAX) -- Variable for string
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
DECLARE @RETURN_STRING VARCHAR(MAX)
 
; WITH  N1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
N2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS X, N1 AS Y),
N3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS X, N2 AS Y),
N4(n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY X.n)
FROM N3 AS X, N3 AS Y)
 
SELECT @RETURN_STRING=ISNULL(@RETURN_STRING,'')+ SUBSTRING(@String,Nums.n,1)
FROM N4 Nums
WHERE Nums.n <=LEN(@String) AND PATINDEX('%[0-9A-Za-z ]%',SUBSTRING(@String,Nums.n,1)) > 0
 
RETURN @RETURN_STRING
END
 
GO
SELECT dbo.[UDF_Extract_Alphanumeric_From_String] ('Hello ## World! Test8.?##') as [Result]

--OUTPUT

Result
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello  World Test8

(1 row affected)


Completion time: 2022-12-20T22:47:24.8872397+01:00
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Will need to read the code to make sure I am understanding what it's doing. I can use it in the select as it's a function. My concern was performance but I just tested it against thousands of records and it works fine. SELECT dbo.UDF_Extract_Alphanumeric_From_String(Name) FROM @table

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach with a UDF...

```
CREATE FUNCTION LeaveValidChars 
(
    @p1 varchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(100)='', @p INT = 0, @c CHAR(1);
    WHILE @p < LEN(@p1)
    BEGIN
        SET @c=substring(@p1, @p, 1)
        IF CHARINDEX(@c,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890?')>0 
            SET @result=@result+@c;
        SET @p=@p+1
    END
    RETURN @Result;
END
GO
```